# BigQuery aggregate and deduplicate array and struct column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In Bigquery, I have source data like this in table.

[image]

I want result like below in view.

[image]

The column `C4` has to be splitted for each entry. The columns `C5` to `C7` shall be grouped as an array.

Answer (score 0):

First build up your povided sample data in the CTE `tbl`. Here the `unnest` is used to build up the data structure with less code.

To obtain your desired result:

The column `C4` has to be splitted by `,` and using `unnest` to duplicate the dataset for each entry.

The data has to be grouped by the first 4 columns. The columns C5 to C7 need to structured in an array. I would go for the `Y` array structure here. If you need the data as individual arrays, please ensure the same ordering for all columns.

```sql
With tbl as (
  Select 121253 as C1, "BUS00978" as C2,
  "X1715002620" as C3,
  "USH,ADC,LEV" as C4, X.*
  from unnest([struct("Material" as C5,"Rote Copper" as C6,True as C7),struct("Brand","Mueller",False),struct("Actual Heihght","0.5",False)]) X
  )

  Select 
  C1,C2,C3,C4_new,
  array_agg(struct(C5,C6,C7) order by C5) as Y,
  array_agg(C5 order by C5,C6) as C5,
  array_agg(C6 order by C5,C6) as C6,
  array_agg(C7 order by C5,C6) as C7,
   from tbl, unnest(split(C4,',')) as C4_new
   group by 1,2,3,4
   order by 1,2,3,4 asc
```